# Prove that BA cannot be invertible (A and B are linear transformations). Give an example of AB which is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The exact question I am trying to solve is as follows:

Let A: $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ and B: $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be linear transformations, so BA: $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ and AB: $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$.

a) Prove that BA cannot be invertible.

b) Give an example of A and B such that AB is invertible.

A couple of things I've tried so far: From a theorem in my textbook "A linear transformation: T: V$\rightarrow$W is invertible if and only if it is one-to-one and onto." I thought about trying to show that BA was either not one-to-one or not onto. Since $Ker(T)=0$ implies one-to-one, I thought about showing that there must be a non-zero vector in BA. Not really sure where to go with this.

I've tried searching the internet for similar questions but have not had any luck. The only thing I've come across that may be helpful is the following:

I found a proof showing that if UT is one-to-one then T is one-to-one. If UT is is onto, then U is onto. If U and T are one-to-one and onto, then UT must also be one-to-one and onto. Not sure if these really help because it says "Let V, W, Z be vector spaces and let $T : V \to W$ and $U : W \to Z$ be linear." So this is essentially proving the invertibility of AB, in my question, but I am interested in disproving the invertibility of BA, or TU from this proof (if I'm right).

I am also not sure where to start with coming up with an A and B such that AB is invertible.

I am only in an introductory linear algebra course and I am doing these problems to prepare for my exam, which may or may not include this question. Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hint: Is it possible for $\operatorname{kernel} A =\{0\}$?

Comment: Hint. Think about whether $BA$ can be onto. There's some easily available information about the dimension of its range. For $AB$ think about the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: I know that, since A maps R^3 to R^2, then vectors from the domain must be mapped to more than one vector from the codomain, since the dimension of R^3 is 3 and dimension of R^2 is 2, meaning that A cannot be one-to-one and therefore Ker(A) cannot be equal to 0. But how would I use this fact to disprove the invertibility of BA?

Answer (score 2):

The rank of $A$ is at most $2$. So, the rank of $BA$ is at most $2$ and, since $BA$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^3$ into itself, it cannot be surjective and so it canot be invertible.

On the other hand, you can take $B(x,y)=(x,y,0)$ and $A(x,y,z)=(x,y)$. So$$A\bigl(B(x,y,z)\bigr)=A(x,y,0)=(x,y).$$

Comment: Why does the rank of BA being at most 2 help conclude that it cannot be surjective? By the Rank Theorem: rank(BA)=dimR^3-nullity(BA). Does the fact that rank(BA) is at most 2 imply that nullity cannot be equal to 0 because it would not satisfy the equality, and hence BA is not surjective? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The rank is the dimension of the range. If the dimension of the range of $BA$ is at most $2$, then, since $\dim\mathbb R^3=3$, the range of $BA$ cannot possibly be $\mathbb R^3$.